# Generalization of Mahalanobis distance, but for matrices rather than vectors

Tags: matrices

As a structural equation modeler, I am trying to learn more about formulas like:

$$ Q = (s - \sigma)^{-1} \bf{M} (s - \sigma) $$

which seem to be a sort of Mahalanobis distance, but where $s$ and $\sigma$ are elements of an $N * N$ matrix rather than being elements of a simple vector.

Articles like [this](https://bmcresnotes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1756-0500-3-267) one (equation 2, further down the page) show a version of the formula, but chronically fail to specify what exactly the $\bf{M}$ matrix should be.  According to that article, there are several ways the $\bf{M}$ matrix can be constructed, but too many articles fail to give enough specificity for me to be able to actually construct it myself.

Can anyone give me more detail about how the $\bf{M}$ elements should be constructed?  A reference to an answer would be acceptable as well.

TIA.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "Mahalanobis distance" at all. This is a very common construction when working in vector spaces. $s$ and $\sigma$ are vectors, not matrices. There is no such thing as $(s-\sigma)^{-1}$ as vectors do not have inverses. The correct interpretation of the $'$ in the article is the *transpose* of the vector, not an inverse. so $$Q = (s - \sigma)^T\mathbf M(s - \sigma)$$ That is, you start with the vector $s - \sigma$, transform it into a new vector by $\mathbf M$, and take the inner product of the original and new vectors.

Comment: The reason you aren't told how the $\mathbf M$ matrix is constructed (at least in that article) is because $\mathbf M$ appears to be what the article is about finding, and it is only giving an overview, not the actual procedures (and IMO the authors are more concerned with seeming scholarly than being understood). You take an initial guess at $\Bbb M$, then use an iterative process to keep improving the guess (by changing $M$ to make $Q$ smaller). There are several available methods, but this article does not dive into those details - you'll have to follow the references.